Deriving a General Expression for $\sin A\times\sin 2A\times\sin 4A\times\sin 8A\dots\times\sin 2^nA$
Hey so I'm currently preparing for an entrance examination, and have found this particular formula of great help while solving questions on cosines of angles in a GP.
$$\cos A\times\cos 2A\times\cos 4A\times\cos 8A\dots\cos (2^nA)=\frac{\sin(2^{n+1}A)}{2^n\sin A}$$
I attempted to derive a similar formula for sines of angles in a GP.
$$\sin A\times\sin 2A\times\sin 4A\times\sin 8A\dots\sin (2^nA)=(?)$$
I started by multiplying this expression by $\frac{2\cos A}{2\cos A}$ to obtain the following by using the Double-Angle Identity:
$$\frac{2\cos A\times\sin A\times\sin 2A\times\sin 4A\dots\sin (2^nA)}{2\cos A}=\frac{\sin^2 2A\times\sin 4A\dots\sin (2^nA)}{2\cos A}$$
I continued this method, attempting to eliminate almost all sines, after which I could use the previously derived expression for cosines.
I obtained this expression in the end, but I'm unsure about how to proceed further.
$$\frac{\sin^{n+1}(2^nx)}{2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\cos^k(2^{k-1}x)^n}$$

Related, but there doesn't seem to exist a general closed form.

You can't simplify this. For the cos expression, the $\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$ form automatically counters the $\cos(2x)$ which isn't the case for $\sin(x)$ GP. Also if you don't mind, what entrace exam are you preparing for?

Yea I thought as much.
And I'm preparing for the JEE btw, it's an engineering entrance examination in India.

@Schrödinger'sCat advanced right? which institute? chaitanya?

The question is about the expression
$$ B_n(A) := \sin A\cdot\sin 2A\cdot\sin 4A\cdot\sin 8A\cdots\sin (2^nA). \tag1$$
The key is to use the standard identities
$$ \sin A = \frac1{2i}(x - x^{-1}),\;\;
\cos A = \frac1{2}(x + x^{-1}),\;\;
 x:=e^{iA}. \tag2$$
Use this in equation $(1)$ to get
$$ B_n(A) = (2i)^{-n}\prod_{k=0}^n\left(x^{2^k} - x^{-2^k}\right). \tag3 $$
Expand this as a
Laurent polynomial
in $x$ to get (when $\,n\,$ is even)
$$ B_n(A) = (2i)^{-n-1}(-1)^{n-1}\!\sum_{j=1}^{2^n-1}
   s_j\left(x^j-x^{-j}\right) \tag4 $$
where $\,s_j\,$ is zero if $j$ is even else
$$ s_{2k+1} = a_k := (-1)^{\text{wt}(k)} \tag5 $$
where $\,a_k\,$ is
OEIS sequence A106400 and
$\,\text{wt}(k)\,$ is the
Hamming weight
of the bits of integer $k$.
For example,
$$ B_1(A) = 2^{-1}(\cos A - \cos 3A ) \tag7 $$
$$ B_2(A) =-2^{-2}(\sin A - \sin 3A  - \sin 5A  + \sin 7A). \tag8 $$
Thus the result for $\,n\,$ even is
$$ B_n(A) = (2i)^{-n}\!\sum_{j=1}^{2^{n+1}-1}
   s_j \sin(jA). \tag9 $$
The slightly different result for $\,n\,$ odd is
$$ B_n(A) = i(2i)^{-n}\!\sum_{j=1}^{2^{n+1}-1}
  s_j \cos(jA). \tag{10} $$
Whether this can be accepted as a "general expression" or "closed form"
is a matter of opinion.
The explanation of why the result differs depending on $\,n\,$ being
even or odd is that each factor of the product is an odd function and
thus the product $\,B_n(A)\,$ is an odd or even function depends on
the parity of $\,n\,$ itself.

However, the question is motivated by the example of
$$ C_n(A) := \cos A\cdot\cos 2A\cdot\cos 4A\cdot\cos 8A\cdots\cos (2^nA) \tag{11}$$
using the standard identity
$$ \text{sinc}(2x)/\text{sinc}(x) = \cos(x) $$
to get the general result
$$ C_n(A) = \text{sinc}(2^{n+1}A)/\text{sinc}(A). \tag{12} $$
Thus, consider the function
$$ f(x) \!=\! 1 \!-\! \frac{x^2}{18}
 \!+\! \frac{19x^4}{16200} 
 \!-\! \frac{583x^6}{42865200}
 \!+\! \frac{132809x^8}{1311675120000}
 \!+\! \cdots
\tag{13} $$
which satisfies
$$ f(2x)/f(x) = \text{sinc}(x) := \sin(x)/x. \tag{14} $$
This implies
$$ B_n(A) = x^{n+1} 2^{2^n-1}f(2^{n+1}A)/f(A). \tag{15} $$
I don't think that the function $\,f(x)\,$ has a closed form
expression although
$$ f(x) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \text{sinc}(x/2^k). \tag{16} $$

Let $A_n(x)$ be the cosine odd multiple angle sum
\begin{align}
A_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\cos((2k-1)x)}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
B_n(x)= 2^n \sin^{n+1}(x) \prod_{i=1}^n{A_{2^{i-1}}(x)} = \sin(x)\sin(2x)\sin(4x)\sin(8x)...\sin(2^n x)
\end{align}
is a general expression for your product
